# MIME::Parser fails to parse multipart/mixed parts correctly

Tags: perl, mime

I have a server sending me this response. However, using the following code I end up with an entity containing no parts and everything between the boundaries (inclusive) as the MIME::Body. Is there something I can do short of implementing my own multipart parser (in general there may be more parts) and scrapping the modules that are supposed to do it for me?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Parser;

my $response = <<_EOF;
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="be4dc417ebd640944ab26f033e5ea1ab"

--be4dc417ebd640944ab26f033e5ea1ab
Content-Type: application/json

{"a":"b"}
--be4dc417ebd640944ab26f033e5ea1ab--
_EOF

my $mime_parser = new MIME::Parser;
$mime_parser->tmp_to_core(1);
$mime_parser->output_to_core(1);
my $entity = $mime_parser->parse_data($response);

print "$MIME::Parser::VERSION $^V $^O\n\n";
$entity->print(\*STDOUT);
print "\n\n";
print $entity->parts(0)->bodyhandle->as_string;
```

Output:

```
5.502 v5.10.1 MSWin32


--be4dc417ebd640944ab26f033e5ea1ab
Content-Type: application/json

{"a":"b"}
--be4dc417ebd640944ab26f033e5ea1ab--


Can't call method "bodyhandle" on an undefined value at test.pl line 25.
```

Comment: For me, `$entity->parts(0)` returns a MIME::Entity instance whose body is only `{"a":"b"}`, so post a complete program that is runnable stand-alone to properly demonstrate your problem. -- `$entity->bodyhandle->as_string` throws the error `Can't call method "as_string" on an undefined value`, this is a programming error, you want `$entity->parts(0)->bodyhandle->as_string`.

Comment: Hmm. Will check my versions and post complete program tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` line is not part of the MIME response.  Take it out and it works fine.